# Bundler: Command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I am hosting on a vps, ubuntu 10.04, rails 3, ruby and mysql installed correctly by following some tutorials. If I run `bundle check` or `bundle install` I get the error '-bash: bundle: command not found'. From `gem list --local` I see 'bundler (1.0.2, 1.0.0)' is installed.

I don't know what's going wrong...

`gem environment` returns:

```
 RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-04-19 patchlevel 253) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /root/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

and `echo $PATH` returns:

```
/opt/myruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/bin/gem:/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/:/root/.gem/ruby/1.8
```

and `which gem` returns:

```
/usr/bin/gem
```

`locate bundle` returns:

```
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/
```

Comment: have you install bundler ?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You need to add the ruby gem executable directory to your path

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin
```

Comment: Under uBuntu 11.04, the latest command path is now
export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin

Comment: Update: under ubuntu 11.04, it seems the path is irrelevant, because as long as we want to use the latest RubyGem, we just need to install RVM and install desired Ruby version.

Comment: Antony that worked for me and I've submitted an update to the main answer.

Comment: For Arch Linux, use export PATH=$PATH:~/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin (adjust for your version of Ruby)

Comment: For rvm use `export /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:$PATH` or `ENV PATH /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:$PATH` with Docker.

Answer (score 218):

My problem was that I did:

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

So I had installed as root rather than as myself. So I uninstalled as root, then installed as myself:

```
sudo gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler
rbenv rehash
```

(last command for if you are using rbenv)

And it worked. The "correct" path *was* in `.bashrc` (or other shell profile), at least according to

```
$PATH
=> zsh: /Users/myself/.rbenv/shims:/Users/myself/.rbenv/bin: ... etc
```

but it was expecting it to be installed for myself - not for root. In my case, its rightful installation place is in `~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler`

Comment: rbenv is an alternative to RVM. It manages all your different ruby versions. When you install a gem with `gem install` it installs it alongside the currently used version of ruby which you can see when you do `rbenv versions` (it should be marked with a *). When you install the bundler gem, you can `bundle install` gems which will let you install gems on a per-project basis. The gems you tend to `gem install` are things like bundler and zeus. When you `gem install`, you need to run `rbenv rehash` afterwards. Its just how it is.

Comment: I had this problem on Windows. Rang `gem install bundler` and it's all good now.

Answer (score 26):

... also for Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 :)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
```

Comment: Didnt work for me, any suggestions?
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
     - /kunden/homepages/11/dxxxxxx/htdocs/.gem/ruby/1.8
echo $
PATH
~/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/bin:/usr/local/ms
:/kunden/homepages/11/d3xxxxxx/htdocs/.rvm/bin:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:/var/lib/
gems/1.8/bin

Answer (score 17):

I did this (Ubuntu latest as of March 2013 [ I think :) ]):

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

Credit goes to [Ray Baxter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6675410).

If you need gem, I installed Ruby this way (though this is chronically taxing):

```
mkdir /tmp/ruby && cd /tmp/ruby
wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p327.tar.gz
tar xfvz ruby-1.9.3-p327.tar.gz
cd ruby-1.9.3-p327
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably distro-proof path is adding this to your .bashrc or .zshrc, whatever your shell is :

```
PATH="$(ruby -e 'print Gem.default_dir')/bin:$PATH"
```

or if you have installed your gems user-wide, use :

```
PATH="$(ruby -e 'print Gem.user_dir')/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 4):

For rbenv users:

```
$ rbenv versions
2.6.0
$ rbenv global 2.6.0
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.0p0
$ gem install bundler
$ rbenv rehash
$ bundle
$ rails -v
Command 'rails' not found
$ rbenv rehash
$ rails -v
Rails 4.2.11.1
```

Comment: key is `rbenv rehash`

Answer (score 3):

I'm running ubuntu 11.10 and bundle executable was located in:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to make sure I selected a version of Ruby for that repo.

Example: `chruby 2.2.2` or `rvm use 2.2.2`

```
λ bundle install
zsh: command not found: bundle

λ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]

### Notice the system Ruby version isn't included in chruby

λ chruby
  ruby-1.9.3-p551
  ruby-2.1.2
  ruby-2.2.1

### Select a version via your version manager

λ chruby 1.9.3

### Ensure your version manager properly selects a version (*)

λ chruby
 * ruby-1.9.3-p551
   ruby-2.1.2
   ruby-2.2.1

λ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this error `rbenv: bundle: command not found` after cloning an old rails project I had built a couple on months ago.
here is how I went about it:
To install a specific version of bundler or just run the following command to install the latest available bundler:

run `gem install bundler`

then I installed the exact version of bundler I wanted with this command:

`$ gem install bundler -v "$(grep -A 1 "BUNDLED WITH" Gemfile.lock | tail -n 1)"`

[check this article for more details](https://www.aloucaslabs.com/miniposts/rbenv-bundle-command-not-found#:~:text=When%20you%20get%20the%20rbenv,to%20install%20the%20Bundler%20gem
[check this article for more details](https://bundler.io/blog/2019/05/14/solutions-for-cant-find-gem-bundler-with-executable-bundle.html)

get the listen to work by issuing this command

`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`

Answer (score 2):

On my Arch Linux install, gems were installed to the `~/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin` directory if installed as user, or `/root/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin` if installed via `sudo`. Just append the appropriate one to your `$PATH` environment variable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/your_username/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do `rbenv rehash` when installing different rubies

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:Make sure you are on path actual workspace.For example, workspace/blog $: 
Step2:Enter the command:  gem install bundler.
Step 3: You should be all set to bundle install  or bundle update by now

Answer (score 0):

I think bundle executable is on :

`/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bin` and it's not in your $PATH

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a symlink:

```
ln -s /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bin/bundle /usr/bin/bundle
```

Comment: `ln -s /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bin/bundle /usr/bin/bundle` it should be this with an extra `bundle` you wanna create sym link to bundle rather than the whole bin dir ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and was able to resolve it by running

```
rbenv rehash
```

After that `bundle` worked as expected. Upon taking a look at the rbenv wiki entry it does mention that rehash should be run when an installed gem provides commands.

> Installs shims for all Ruby executables known to rbenv (i.e.,
>   ~/.rbenv/versions/*/bin/*). Run this command after you install a new
>   version of Ruby, or install a gem that provides commands.

Apparently this is such an annoyance that some folks have written a gem to make sure you never need to run `rehash` again.
[rbenv-gem-rehash](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-gem-rehash)