# bundle command not found in linux debian

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When i enter `bundle install`  I get the error '-bash: bundle: command not found'.

How do I find whether bundler is installed ?

gem environment returns the following

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.2.0
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

Can somebody explains me how to get the bundler command working ?
I am a novice to this subject..

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
gem install bundler
```

or probably, since there is an executable

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

Comment: I'm getting the ERROR:  Error installing bundler:
        bundler requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6

Comment: well im getting this error for gem update --system ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    gem update --system is disabled on Debian. RubyGems can be updated using the official Debian repositories by aptitude or apt-get. But apt-get upgrade gem is also not working..

Comment: add the gem binary to your environement : export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/:${PATH}    then you can use bundle

Comment: Ah, was searching for 1 hour and got this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 38):

In addition to installing

```
gem install bundler
```

you need to put the gem installation directory in your path
on Debian 11.04 with gems v1.8 I used

```
export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/:${PATH}
```