# no such file to load -- rdoc/task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake, rdoc

When I run

```
rake db:create
```

I receive this error

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- rdoc/task

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is the --trace

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/tpeg/rails_apps/Test/Rakefile:8
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

I have rake 0.9.2 and rdoc 3.11 installed. I am running these commands in my app's directory.

Comment: have you executed `bundle install` before?

Comment: It gives me: bundle: command not found

Comment: please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914694/bundle-command-not-found) out

Comment: That isn't very helpful. I have bundler installed, but it still says it cannot find it.

Comment: try `updatedb` and then `whereis bundle`

Comment: updatedb returns: updatedb: can not open a temporary file for `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db' | whereis bundle returns: bundle:

Comment: operating system, what distributive if it's linux

Comment: did you find a solution and what was it? (me myself have had similar problems but since I started to use rvm together with bundler they are gone)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I solved it by adding `gem 'rdoc'` to my Gemfile and then run `bundle install`.

Comment: Where is your "Gemfile"? Is it some system file or something else?

Comment: Gemfile is a text file located at the root of your rails app. The purpose of this file is to indicate which gems your application requires.

Comment: Having this issue working with a legacy rails 2 app. before bundle none of this stuff was included :D

Answer (score 13):

If you're not using a Gemfile, it's likely that switching your line in your Rakefile from this:

```
require 'rake/rdoctask'
```

to this

```
require 'rdoc/task'
```

will work. It did for me.

Also try a

```
gem install rdoc
```

Answer (score 4):

You can actually trap for this in your Rakefile should you have different rake versions between environments. We are this way with older production applications.

```
begin
  require 'rake/rdoctask'
rescue
  require 'rdoc/task'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're working on an app without a Gemfile (like a legacy with rails 2.3 --), you can install the gem rdoc manually:

gem install rdoc