# rake db:create issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rakefile

I have just started working on one project, and I have configured my system according to the requirement of the project i.e.

```
rails v => 2.3.11
ruby v => 1.8.7
```

When i run command "rake db:create" it comes up with error as

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- rake/rdoctask
/home/jeet/Desktop/Projects/myapp/Rakefile:8
```

here i am adding the content of Rakefile

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))

require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rake/rdoctask'

require 'tasks/rails'
```

I have checked the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826442/no-such-file-to-load-rdoc-task), but its not working for me.

Please suggest me a better solution

Comment: Which version of `rdoc` are you using? http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/howto-fix-rake-rdoctask-is-deprecated-use-rdoc-task-instead-1169.html Looks like it has been deprecated.

Comment: I am using "rdoc (3.12)"

Comment: Try to look at this question maybe it helps you [stackoverflow][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826442/no-such-file-to-load-rdoc-task

Comment: Not sure about the error maybe "bundle exec rake db:create"? Or try "gem list", rdoc available?

Comment: Fillky, i have already mentioned in my question that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826442/no-such-file-to-load-rdoc-task is not working for me

Comment: Thanks SG, I have got my solution with the help of my friend. The error was due to the two version of rake in my fem list, i have remove one of them and then executed "bundle exec rake db:create" and its all done....... Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same problem.

Possible solution: by adding gem `'rdoc'` to my Gemfile and then run `bundle install`.