# Error message when trying to run rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I keep having this problem when trying to run inside directory that has server folder. Somewhere else, it's fine and says Rails 3.2.8. Here is the problem message: ( I use ruby 1.9.2 )

```
$ rails -v  
/Users/ngockhanhdao/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/script_rails_loader.rb:11: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
Could not find builder-3.0.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I installed bundle and it says:

```
$ sudo bundle install
/Users/ngockhanhdao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [actionmailer-3.2.8, actionpack-3.2.8, activemodel-3.2.8, activerecord-3.2.8, activeresource-3.2.8, activesupport-3.2.8, arel-3.0.2, builder-3.0.3, erubis-2.7.0, hike-1.2.1, i18n-0.6.1, journey-1.0.4, json-1.7.5, mail-2.4.4, mime-types-1.19, multi_json-1.3.6, polyglot-0.3.3, rack-1.4.1, rack-cache-1.2, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.2, rails-3.2.8, railties-3.2.8, rdoc-3.12, rubygems-update-1.8.24, sprockets-2.1.3, thor-0.16.0, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.10, tzinfo-0.3.33] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/ngockhanhdao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/ngockhanhdao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /Users/ngockhanhdao/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

Thanks

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914694/bundle-command-not-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing both `builder` and `bundler` gems... do `gem install bundler` then do a `bundle install`

Not sure if you will need to `sudo` those commands...

Comment: `bundle install` should never be used with `sudo`, as it will install the gems as `root` and, depending on the environment, could restrict the application's access to those files. It goes against the whole point of Bundler.