# capistrano sidekiq: command not found: bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler, sidekiq

Trying to deploy with capistrano (`Bundle exec cap production deploy`), I run into this error:

first

```
** Invoke deploy:restart_sidekiq (first_time)
** Execute deploy:restart_sidekiq
** Invoke sidekiq:restart (first_time)
** Execute sidekiq:restart
** Invoke sidekiq:stop
** Invoke sidekiq:start (first_time)
** Execute sidekiq:start
```

after which

```
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deployer@99.999.99.999: sidekiq exit status: 127
sidekiq stdout: Nothing written
sidekiq stderr: zsh:1: command not found: bundle
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:16:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
SSHKit::Command::Failed: sidekiq exit status: 127
sidekiq stdout: Nothing written
sidekiq stderr: zsh:1: command not found: bundle
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/command.rb:95:in `exit_status='
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:179:in `block in _execute'
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `tap'
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `_execute'
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-sidekiq-0.5.4/lib/capistrano/tasks/sidekiq.rake:118:in `start_sidekiq'
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-sidekiq-0.5.4/lib/capistrano/tasks/sidekiq.rake:164:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-sidekiq-0.5.4/lib/capistrano/tasks/sidekiq.rake:37:in `block (2 levels) in for_each_process'
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:77:in `within'
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-sidekiq-0.5.4/lib/capistrano/tasks/sidekiq.rake:36:in `block in for_each_process'
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-sidekiq-0.5.4/lib/capistrano/tasks/sidekiq.rake:35:in `each'
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-sidekiq-0.5.4/lib/capistrano/tasks/sidekiq.rake:35:in `each_with_index'
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-sidekiq-0.5.4/lib/capistrano/tasks/sidekiq.rake:35:in `for_each_process'
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-sidekiq-0.5.4/lib/capistrano/tasks/sidekiq.rake:163:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-sidekiq-0.5.4/lib/capistrano/tasks/sidekiq.rake:226:in `switch_user'
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-sidekiq-0.5.4/lib/capistrano/tasks/sidekiq.rake:162:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/Users/glennjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => sidekiq:start
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deployer@99.999.99.999: sidekiq exit status: 127
sidekiq stdout: Nothing written
sidekiq stderr: zsh:1: command not found: bundle
** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
** Execute deploy:failed
```

I've tried to solve the problem with:

- (local)  `sudo gem install bundler` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914694/bundle-command-not-found))
- on server: `bundle install` & `rbenv rehash`, no change

Weird thing: another developer on my team, **can** simply deploy with the same command. This lead me to think it was an SSH-problem. [Capistrano ssh-doctor](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-ssh-doctor) however reports this is not the case.

Also, I have found [this](https://github.com/capistrano/rvm/issues/43) discussion, where they basically suggest altering the deploy.rb file. I'm hesitant to try this since we use rbenv and not rvm. Since I don't know what I'm doing here, I don't want to break the production server..

Any ideas or suggestions to what might cause this? And where to look to figure out how to solve it?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by removing my `gemfile.lock` and replacing it with an older version. (I had `bundle update`'d somewhere - don't randomly bundle update).