# A manual for Building ios parse SDK

Tags: ios, parse-platform, sdk

I am trying to build the parse SDK for iOS client using this repo [Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX) I get a compiler error in Bolt that Xcode can't find

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

I fixed the missing UIKit problem by manually Building Bolts by opening Bolts.xcodeproj then build it

I did what is in the repo's Readme file

```
# To pull in extra dependencies (Bolts and OCMock)
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

this worked fine, Next lines did not work

```
# To install all the gems
bundle install
```

**output:** -bash: bundle: command not found
I fixed this using code in this answer [bundle: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914694/bundle-command-not-found#17316481)

```
# Build & Package the Frameworks
rake package:frameworks
```

**output:** rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- naturally

What I am asking is about any manual for building the parse SDK and getting the Parse-iOS.zip

Comment: just out of curiosity why dont you use Cocoapods?

Comment: I want to add some behavior to parse SDK making a proxy the consumer has to call it before the SDK